# Data type mismatch exception when trying to compare excel rows of general or type to a string using OleDbCommand

Tags: asp.net, c, excel, datatable, oledb

In order to make my application faster, I am trying to fetch a row where the 'Vertical_num' column matches the given string.The below code

```
 using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(con))
            {
                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [All Verticals$] where Vertical_num ='"+t+"'", connection);

                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                System.Data.DataTable dt1 = new System.Data.DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt1);
                for (int i=0;i<dt1.Rows.Count;i++)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(dt1.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString());
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
```

It prints the required value when the value in my excel file column is 1000_1 but when the value in the column is 10001 it returns "Data type mismatch exception"
How can I modify my query to match all types of cell value?
The type of my excel column is general, I changed it to text but the same error was returned.